# Put existing .git folder into TFS

Tags: git, tfs

I have a .git folder that was created with `git init` on the commandline and populated with files using the typical `git add` and `git commit` commands.

Our systems people have updated TFS such that it now supports git so I want to move this onto a server.

How can I put my existing .git folder into TFS and retain all history?

I have googled this and found other Stack Overflow questions on this topic but they talk about solutions files and other things I am not familiar with.

This is *not* a .NET project.  It is just some SQL files and batch scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a repo in your team project. The empty repo's landing page will give explicit instructions that you can copy and paste. In general, though:

```
git remote add origin <url-to-remote-repo>

git push -u origin --all
```